# SSIS File System Task Deleting Directory Leaves Directory and Removes all Permissions

Tags: sql, vb.net, ssis

I have a rather bizarre issue with an SSIS package I have. After processing some files within a Directory I am removing the Directory so my For Each Loop doesn't process the same files again.

It fails to Delete the Directory but yet leaves it in the folder and then tells me I do not have access to this folder, I cannot take ownership of it or even move it to another directory.

I have even tried a VB.NET Script tasks to try and remove it and I get the same result.

A reboot of the server makes the folder disappear - has anyone experienced this before.

Regards,

JML

Comment: Why do you need to remove the directory? If there's nothing in it, there's nothing to process anyway? By 'fails to remove the directory', do you mean the package throws an error indicatig failure, or you can still see the directory in windows explorer even though the package says it's deleted it? Given the reboot outcome, it sounds like the folder is indeed deleted, it's just slow to show you that. Is it visibile if you go into CMD and type DIR?

Comment: Which user was it that created the directory intially? How did you start the SSIS package? Locally or did you deploy it on a server? It can be that when you start your SSIS package - e.g. on a server machine - it is executed with a different user than you are currently logged on with. Then your directory would be created with a different account, which could lead to different security settings for this folder... Just a thought.

Comment: I remove the directory because the SSIS package loops through the directories each dir name is a unique client reference. If a Folder/Directory Exists then the mechanism sees it as a Client to process in the Package. Essentially removing the folder removes the need to process it.  The user that created the Directory initially is a Save Process done in a VBA Task in Outlook.  An email comes in, the attachments are saved and the folder is determined by some information in the Body of the email.

Comment: The SSIS Package is started via SQL Agent although the same process fails running the package locally in my devenv.  It fails on both server and locally, although I will try and investigate the security issues.  I can delete the folder myself without a problem - its only when something such as SSIS or another process tries to delete it.  Cheers for the replies.

Comment: ElectricLlama - the folder still is visible in CMD, however if I try and access it using CMD it says Access is Denied. As soon as I reboot the box - the folder has disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the directory is "in use" still but with the deletion pending. When you reboot, the lock on the directory is cleared and the deletion completes. The discussion at

[try ing to move a file "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4171626c-a67d-4ac6-98b2-cbe48b626c22/try-ing-to-move-a-file-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is-being-used-by-another?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

may be helpful.